# dateTimeNoMillis() formatter in ISODateTimeFormat

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I need to validate a string whether it is in the format ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().

```
final DateTimeFormatter dateHourMinuteSecondFormatter =ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
String s = "2012-W12-12";
try {
        dateHourMinuteSecondFormatter.parseDateTime(s);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.setMessage("exception thrown);
    }
```

It is supposed to throw the exception as the date is in the wrong format but it is not.
Is there anything else that I need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's nothing more you need to do.

I suspect that actually it *is* throwing the example, but your message diagnostics are incorrect. This certainly fails for me, using Joda Time 2.1:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
        String s = "2012-W12-12";
        try {
            DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(s);
            System.out.println(dt);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2012-W12-12" is malformed
at "W12-12"
```

Comment: Code is applying parseDateTime() on "dateHourMinuteSecondFormatter" but not on "formatter".

Comment: @user1772643: Sorry - I edited the name in the first line of code to avoid scrolling horizontally, and forgot to apply it later. It really is was calling it on the same object :) Try the code now.